# Compaq Presario CQ56 won't turn on

Tags: hardware-failure, hp-pavilion, laptop-repair

I have a 2 year old Compaq Presario CQ56 installed Windows 7.

sometimes it turn on, fan spin, led comes and power off instant. but sometime
Nothing happens when turned on - no lights, no buzz from the fan.

This is my backup computer which isn't used much - worked fine with last use, but has been shut down for several days since.

Any ideas and/or suggestions?

Comment: If you have enough skills - find a video/manual about how to disassemble it and try to look inside and check if something is wrong here (i.e. lots of dust). If you're not skilled enough - take it to someone who is (i. e. a service center worker).

Comment: And check it's power cord/outlet of course.

Comment: Maybe the power brick is bad.